# last element of array matching scala

Tags: arrays, regex, scala, pattern-matching

Good afternoon! I'm using Scala and I want to match first three element of a list and the last one, no matter how much of them are in the list.

```
val myList:List[List[Int]] = List(List(3,1,2,3,4),List(23,45,6,7,2),List(3,3,2,1,5,34,43,2),List(8,5,3,34,4,5,3,2),List(3,2,45,56))

def parse(lists: List[Int]): List[Int] = lists.toArray match{
  case Array(item, site, buyer, _*, date) => List(item, site, buyer, date)}

myList.map(parse _)
```

But I get : `error: bad use of _* (a sequence pattern must be the last pattern)`
I understand why I get it, but how can I avoid?

My use case is that I'm reading from hdfs, and every file has exact N (N is constant and equal for all files) columns, so I want to match only some of them, without writing something like `case Array(item1, item2 , ..., itemN) => List(item1, item2, itemK, itemN)`

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to convert lists to Arrays, because lists are designed for pattern matching.

```
scala> myList match { 
  case item :: site :: buyer :: tail if tail.nonEmpty => 
    item :: site :: buyer :: List(tail.last)
}
res3: List[List[Int]] = List(List(3, 1, 2, 3, 4), List(23, 45, 6, 7, 2), 
  List(3, 3, 2, 1, 5, 34, 43, 2), List(3, 2, 45, 56))
```

Or even more concise solution suggested by [Kolmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098230/kolmar)

```
scala> myList match { 
  case item :: site :: buyer :: (_ :+ date) => List(item, site, buyer, date) 
}
```

Comment: You'll want to add an `if(tail.nonEmpty)`, otherwise this will match `List(1, 2, 3)`, but throw a `NoSuchElementException` when you call `tail.last`.

Comment: Or just use `myList match {
  case item :: site :: buyer :: (_ :+ date) => List(item, site, buyer, date) }`

Comment: @Kolmar Wow, that's even better then my original suggestion.